# Which books should I refer to in my master's thesis about parallelism?

Tags: discussion, resources

What books should I read for my thesis about parallelism in rhetorical devices?

Comment: Can you add a little more detail about your thesis? Is it primarily linguistics, primarily rhetoric/philology, or something else/a mix? What have you looked at already? Also is this about parallelism essentially within a rhetorical device (like syllepsis or about different tropes used in parallel?

Comment: Ask your teacher if you don't know.